# MySql Self-Referencing query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a following table named [clients] with columns and values as follows:

```
+--------+-----------+--------------+----------------+
| uid    | client_id | client_input |  input_value   |
+--------+-----------+--------------+----------------+
| 1      |   22      |  City        |  Seattle       |
+--------+-----------+--------------+----------------+
| 2      |   45      |  City        |  Ojai          |
+--------+-----------+--------------+----------------+
| 3      |   22      |  State       |  OR            |
+--------+-----------+--------------+----------------+
| 4      |   45      |  State       |  CA            |
+--------+-----------+--------------+----------------+
| 5      |   65      |  City        |  Orlando       |
+--------+-----------+--------------+----------------+
| 6      |   74      |  State       |  AB            |
+--------+-----------+--------------+----------------+
| 7      |   65      |  State       |  FL            |
+--------+-----------+--------------+----------------+
| 8      |   12      |  City        |  Los Angeles   |
+--------+-----------+--------------+----------------+
| 9      |   12      |  State       |  CA            |
```

I need **PHP/MySql query** which would **list all the cities** present in the **input_value** column which are located in the state of 'CA'. Obviously the common identifier is the **client_id** which is always a match because if client is in **'Los Angeles'** the same client_id is also in the row which contains the value of **'CA'** in the **input_value** column. This table has over 8 million rows and any fast performing equerry is highly appreciated.

My brain fried, deadline approaching, can't change the table design, need help, please!

Comment: Fiddle with above table: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ed3f . Can you show a `create table` statement for your table (to see how it is indexed)?

Comment: So you want all the cities of california for each client? I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table AS t1 INNER JOIN table AS t2 ON t1.client_id = t2.client_id
WHERE t1.client_input = 'City' AND t2.client_input = 'State' AND t2.input_value = 'CA'
```

**Note:** This may need some adjustments and could likely be optimized. But it should get you started and cool your brain.

Comment: Thank for the super fast response. Yes, this will work. However it will not return the cities only. As your SELECT * FROM statement says  it returns the whole row (array) of values matching the query. But with a little PHP array magic I am getting what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I did not tested this query. But this or a similar query should work. I first used two subqueries to avoid unecessary joins. 
The first subquery filters for the state 'CA' and the second subquery for cities. If you want a table for all cities by their state, remove the 'CA' clause from subquery a.

```
SELECT b.input_value AS city, a.input_value AS state
FROM 
  (SELECT client_id, input_value
   FROM tablename
   WHERE input_value = 'CA'
   AND client_input = 'State')
  AS a,
  (SELECT client_id, input_value
   FROM tablename
   WHERE client_input = 'City')
  AS b
WHERE a.client_id = b.client_id
```

Comment: I wish I could make your query to work. I will keep you posted if I do since the join seems expensive and the lag time is almost 2s huh :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct 
      t2.Input_Value as City
   from
      YourTable t1
         JOIN YourTable t2
            on t1.client_ID = t2.Client_ID
           AND t2.client_input = 'City'
   where
          t1.client_input = 'State'
      AND t1.Input_Value = 'CA'
```

I would have two indexes...
(Client_Input, Input_Value)
and
(Client_ID, Client_Input, Input_Value)